# retrieve date from database as another format

Tags: asp.net, oracle, date, format

I'm using oracle as my database, I have a taskdate column as TIMESTAMP. the format it save in  database is  **5/29/2015 10:27:04.000000 AM**. can I convert it into **2015-05-29** this format when I retrieve it out??

Comment: Do you like to **format** the timestamp or **trunc the time part**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the format it save in database is 5/29/2015 10:27:04.000000 AM

**Date/Timestamps** doesn't have any **format**. Oracle doesn't store the date/timestamps in the format you see. The format you see is only for **display** purpose. *Date is internally stored in 7 bytes which is Oracle's proprietary format*.

> can I convert it into 2015-05-29 this format when I retrieve it out??

**For display:**

You need to use **TO_CHAR** along with desired **format model** to display in your desired format.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD') my_tmstmp FROM DUAL;

SYSTIMESTAMP                             MY_TMSTMP
---------------------------------------- ----------
29-MAY-15 11.40.25.054000 AM +05:30      2015-05-29

SQL>
```

**For date-arithmetic:**

For date arithmetic you should leave the **data type** as **date** itself. You could use **TRUNC** to truncate the time portion and leaving only the date portion:

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) my_tmstmp FROM DUAL;

SYSTIMESTAMP                             MY_TMSTMP
---------------------------------------- ----------
29-MAY-15 11.42.41.255000 AM +05:30      2015-05-29

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can. You may either use "cast .. as date" to convert value to date, and then trunc it (in case you want to leave format as date) or use to_char (if want value as character).
Final expressions for both options may be something like that:

```
SELECT TRUNC(CAST(column AS DATE)) FROM your_table...
```

or

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(column, 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM your_table...
```

Comment: No need to explicitly cast the timestamp into date. Trunc would be fine on the timestamp.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, actually it depends on database version. In newer versions TIMESTAMP implicitly casted to DATE and then truncated, so you can use TRUNC(TIMESTAMP)

Comment: It was way back in `9.2.0.1` and later versions could do the implicit conversion. Anyway, under the hood, Oracle does the same thing, `cast timestamp as date`. https://community.oracle.com/thread/374457